# In the Talent series, by Anne McCaffrey, why is Callisto tower limited by Jupiter?

Tags: space, teleportation, anne-mccaffrey

I understand that Jupiter is a very large planet, but why does it matter to the Rowan where in its orbit Callisto tower is, when the difference in spacial differences is minute compared to the overall distance required to 'port carriers to places such as Betelgeuse, Altair, Deneb VIII, Capella...?

Comment: Well, my first thought is the difference might be small compared to interstellar travel, but the difference is very very large when compared to the landing fields on the planet surface they're transporting to.  Also, is the teleport more difficult "through" the planet... can't remember that part...

Comment: Yes, I believe the implication is that it is Jupiter being "in the way" that is the problem.

Comment: how would the planet being in the way effect anything with an instantaneous 'port from one cradle to the other. it isn't physically moving through the planet. surely they if they skip by all the uninhabitable planets between habitable ones, what is one more? and if that great distance is the problem, how can Earth Prime send to those places regardless of planetary location?

Comment: It isn't instantaneous.

Comment: JRE, how do you figure that it isnt instantaneous. in Pegasus in space, Peter and Johnny sent the colony ship and it was immediately visible via telescope. In the Rowan, when Afra sends the Rowan up in her pod, she as immediately above Demos. when they teleport from one room to the other, they do it immediately. their bodies do not go around to find doorways.

Comment: It can't be completely mental, @Tryce.  I remember talk about the space port having momentum flywheels, and the Primes having to throw and catch, and then there's all the support Talents.  Maybe with a one-off effort it's as instant or as far as they want it to be, but when they work in bulk , they need support and details to avoid burning themselves out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My memory of the stories is that the ships still traverse the space between the start and the destination despite it being called "teleportation."

There are no other planets or stars in direct line between Callisto and the destination planets.  To steal a phrase from Douglas Adams:  space is big.

---

Jupiter is close enough to block them at the starting point.   The Rowan can push a load to Jeff  out at Deneb.  She can push it to the side past the star and Jeff can pull it in the rest of the way.

Pushing past Jupiter means you have to go way off to the side - a straight line in those directions would put the load so far away from Deneb that Jeff couldn't grab it.